# PHP : How to merge child arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, loops

**I have :**

```
$colors = array(
    'apple' => array('green', 'red'),
    'grape' => array('green', 'purple'),
);

$countries = array(
    'apple' => array('china', 'usa')
    'grape' => array('spain', 'france')
);
```

**Expected output:**

```
$result = array(
    'apple' => array('green', 'red', 'china', 'usa'),
    'grape' => array('green', 'purple', 'spain', 'france'),
);
```

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: array_merge_recursive($colors,$countries) must be enough

Comment: You are missing a comma in the countries array...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$result = array_merge_recursive($colors, $countries);
```

Read more: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php

Answer (score 1):

Hope this simplest one will be helpful.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/802818)

```
<?php

$colors = array(
    'apple' => array('green', 'red'),
    'grape' => array('green', 'purple'),
);

$countries = array(
    'apple' => array('china', 'usa'),
    'grape' => array('spain', 'france')
);
foreach($colors as $key => &$value)
{
    $value=array_merge($value,$countries[$key]);
}
print_r($colors);
```